# Query - row based table

Tags: c#, sql, database, sybase

I have no control over how the data is saved in this table. However, I have to query the table and combine the data for similar pn_id column as one row/record.

For instance current data structure is as follows,

[image]

Here we have same pn_id repeated with different question ids. This should have been really saved as one pn_id and then each question as a separate column, per my opinion. However, I have to retrieve the below data as one record like this this..

[image]

Any idea how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: If Sybase does't support the pivot operation, I'd just code it myself in C#.  It's not that complex.

Comment: in the data you show, every pn_id has its own question_ids, is there any relation between question_id 152 (for example) and any other question?  Or if there are 300 differnt question_ids, you want 300 columns for each row, with nulls when a given pn_id doesn't have that question id?  You can pivot in any sql with the CASE statement, without a PIVOT keyword.

Comment: Yes I would want 300 columns with null values as I want to join the records from this table with other tables which has data in columns and show it as one record in the C# datagridview. I will check into CASE statement usage in this case. But so far found this link, which seems initially it should solve the problem.. but will spend some time on this later tonight. http://groups.google.com/group/sybase.public.sqlanywhere.general/browse_thread/thread/81792ce38b3817e2?pli=1

Comment: @Phoog can you please give me some hint how would you code this?

Comment: @MSStp I've added an answer with a sketch of the algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some pseudocode for the transform algorithm.  Note that it requires scanning the entire data set twice; there are a few other opportunities to improve the efficiency, for example, if the input data can be sorted.  Also, since it's pseudocode, I haven't added handling for null values.

```
var columnNames = new HashSet<string> { "pn_id" };

foreach (var record in data)
    columnNames.Add(record.question_id.ToString());

var table = new DataTable();
foreach (var name in columnNames)
    table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(name, typeof(string)));

foreach (var record in data)
{
    var targetRecord = CreateNewOrGetExistingRecord(table, record.pn_id);
    targetRecord[record.question_id.ToString()] = record.char_value ?? record.date_value.ToString();
}
```

And here's a sketch of the helper method:

```
DataRow CreateNewOrGetExistingRecord(DataTable table, object primaryKeyValue)
{
    var result = table.Find(primaryKeyValue);
    if (result != null)
        return result;

    //add code here to create a new row, add it to the table, and return it to the caller
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the structure is fine. Wouldn't make sense to have one columns per question because you would have to add a new column every time a new question were added.

Your problem can easily be solved with PIVOT. Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177410.aspx) link for explanation

Comment: I don't think PIVOT is supported in Sybase

Comment: Just to clarify the DB is Sybase SQL Anywhere 9.01 (ASA 9.01)